# Css Layout Fail

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

So i'm trying to make this Show profile Cover as Below:

[image: CSS Layout Problem]

My Code look's like this:

```
<div class="show_cover">
  <%= image_tag @show.cover(:show_cover) %>

  <!-- Mouseover Options-->
  <% if current_user == @host %>
    <div class="options">
      <%= link_to "Edit #{@show.name} Show", edit_show_path, class: "btn btn-embossed btn-danger btn-mini" %>

      <% end %>
    </div>

  <div class="show_cover_info">

    <div class="pull-left">
      <b><%= link_to @show.name, @show %></b><br>
      <small>The Best Show all over the Net</small>
    </div>

    <div class="pull-right">
      <%= link_to root_path,
                  class: "btn btn-embossed btn-mini btn-social-facebook" do %>
        <i class="icon-facebook"></i> | Facebook
      <% end %>

      <%= link_to root_path,
                  class: "btn btn-embossed btn-mini btn-social-twitter" do %>
        <i class="icon-twitter"></i> | Twitter
      <% end %>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

And the Css is this:

```
.show_cover {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.options {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  display:none;
}

.show_cover:hover

.options {
  display:block;

}

.show_cover_info {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.show_cover_info small {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #888;
}
```

But all i'm getting done is this:

[image]

**The Problem:**

The border Radius is not getting arround the Title and Social Buttons. You see the line inbetween? Thats an `<hr>` tag which should go beneath that whole Div to Seperate it from the next session.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you make the working fiddle ? or try putting this .show_cover { overflow; auto; }

Comment: Wow.. overflow: auto; worked just fine.. You mind answering so i can upvote it ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting overflow auto to your wrapper

```
.show_cover {
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
 }
```